# How to click on a child element

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

There many items and I get object of the desired item. But I don't know how can I click on the child element in this object. 
html:

```
  <div class="item">
     <div role="button" tabindex="-1">
        <strong>ItemName2</strong>
     </div>
     <div class="d">
        <div class="item-icon" role="button" tabindex="-1"  style="display: none">
          <i aria-label="icon: add" class="add"></i>    <!-- I need to click on this Item  -->
        </div>
        <div class="item-icon" role="button" tabindex="-1"  style="display: none">
          <i aria-label="icon: del" class="del"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item"> ... </div>
  <div class="item"> ... </div>
  <div class="item"> ... </div>
```

js:

```
 let fBtns = await driver.findElements(By.tagName('strong')); // Find all objects
 let buttons = fBtns.map(elem => elem.getText());
 const allButtons = await Promise.all(buttons);
   console.log(allButtons);  // All object names
 let current = fBtns[fBtns.length - 1];
   console.log(current);    // This is desired object
 await current.click();   // This is click on the object and operates as expected
  // But I need to click on the  <i aria-label="icon: add" class="add"> element
  // How can I click on the desired element?
```

Comment: "This is click on the desired element and operates as expected". What is your question then?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't know what your question is. You call `current.click()` and the comment in the code says it "operates as expected" and then you ask how to click on it... are you getting an exception? If so, what is it, and pleas show the stack trace.

Comment: I need to click on the  <i aria-label="icon: add" class="add"> element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click the element `<i aria-label="icon: del" class="del"></i>`, you can just use an XPath to query directly on the element:

```
await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[div/strong[text()='ItemName2']]/div/div/i[@class='del']")).click()
```

You can probably shorten this a bit to:

```
await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[div/strong[text()='ItemName2']]//i[@class='del']")).click()
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need to click on this <i ...> element in the current item

Comment: @Александр Updated my answer. This clicks on the `i` element under `ItemName2`.

Comment: i element locates in the div element class='d'. And div element class d locates beside div element with role=button which includes ItemName2. And all this elements locate in the div element class=item.

Comment: Error: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[div/strong[text()='ItemName2']]//i[@class='add']

Comment: The first path in the answer should work for you. Both paths have been tested against your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Try invoking click by trigger method:

`$('.item-icon .add').trigger("click");`

Comment: Give me please answer on JS.

Comment: try: document.getElementsByClassName("add").click();

Comment: There are many items  <div class="item"> with the same structure ( in my html code )

Comment: try giving them a unique id and use: document.getElementById("the id").click();

Comment: I don't have id

Comment: you might need Jquery then

Comment: I click on the parent element. And I can do it. But my trigger will be work, when I click on the daughter element in it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202904/discussion-between-arsal-khan-and-).

Answer (score 1):

In the below example, I scan the document for a dynamic xpath that finds the strong with string ItemName2 and then traverse back up one level (/../) before moving back down to the child element. This will act like a waitForElement that you can hopefully repurpose to trigger a click.

```
var MyDefaultTimeout = 1500; 
    var loaded = false;
    do { 
        var icon = document.getElementsByClassName('//*[contains(@strong,\'ItemName2\')]/../div/div/i');
        if(!icon.length == 0)
           {
            setTimeout(function() { loaded = false }, MyDefaultTimeout);
           }
        else
           { 
           if(!document.readyState === 'complete')
              {
               setTimeout(function() { loaded = false }, MyDefaultTimeout);
              }
           else
              {
               loaded = true;
               return document.readyState;
              }
           }
        }
        while(loaded === false);
```